# Things one needs to know while writing a game engine

Tags: game-engine

I have been dabbling in game development as a hobby for a while now, and I cannot seam to quite get my games to sparkle at least a bit with some graphics. I have decided to write a simple test game engine that only focuses on the representation of graphics - shapes, textures and surfaces.

While I have a few very simple game engines designed for my own games under my belt, I want to create a game engine that I can use to display and play with graphics. I'm going to do this in C++. Since this is my first time with a major engine, the engine in not going to focus on 3D graphics, it's going to be a mixture of isometric and 2D graphics.

My previous engines have incorporated (been able to draw) or focused on simple flat (almost 2D) non impressive graphic designs and representations of:

> - the player
> - NPCs
> - objects
> - walls and surfaces
> - textures

Also, I had some basic ***AI*** and sometimes even ***sound***.

They also ***saved*** and ***loaded*** games.

They didn't have a map editor or a level editor. Is this going to be a problem in the future? At this time I have to point out that some of my games didn't get finished because I was to lazy to write the few last levels.

My question at this point would be: What are some things one should know if one wants to write (develope) a better graphical game engine with all it's functions.

Comment: This question is a little to vague for stackoverflow.com.  If you want some ideas to get started on game programming, try asking on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com, or if you need more general advice about programming, try http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Actually, I just need tips and encouragement for something I'm developing. Maybe the question should be more specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd grab the source that has been released by various game houses (Quake engine etc) and go from there.

Learning from existing greatness is a good way to get your head around things you don't know yet, especially those things that you don't even know you don't know.